# Module / plugin management tools similar to how Wordpress works?

Tags: framework

I am working on creating an application which is intended to be installed on a web server within the intranet of a company. I am looking to create this using PHP/MySQL (or another web programming language) and run it on that web server. This will NOT be a Windows application. Users will access the application through their browsers.

The application will have different modules - e.g. meeting room module, events module, car parking module, etc. The company can chose to install any of them. There can be dependencies (e.g.: "car parking module" needs to be installed for "events module" to work, etc.)

Are there frameworks which allow me to manage my custom modules - checking for dependencies, installing them, allowing updates? Sort of like what a self-hosted WordPress setup does - it tells you if there are updates available for the modules, allows you to search for new modules, install them, etc.

There will be no external developers.

Comment: Should a solution do nothing more than managing those modules? So a whole Web framework/CMS (e.g., something like WordPress) wouldn’t be a suitable solution?

Comment: That's correct - I'm looking to replicate that functionality / aspect of Wordpress, but not have Wordpress itself.

Comment: I never used it but I heard that Drupal is a CMS lower level than Wordpress, working with blocks (an equivalent of WP's modules I think). You may ask a Drupal expert about it.